# Node-soap client-server testing

Tags: javascript, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I need to create a Soap server but only for testing purpose.
My soap client works with the real soap-service, but not with my.
index.js and server.js are in the same folder level.

wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://corpwsdl.oneninetwo" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://corpwsdl.oneninetwo" xmlns:intf="http://corpwsdl.oneninetwo" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns1="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema targetNamespace="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <complexType name="CFCInvocationException">
                <sequence/>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="CFCInvocationException">
        <wsdl:part name="fault" type="tns1:CFCInvocationException"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="searchResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="searchReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="searchRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="xml" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="IDSearch">
        <wsdl:operation name="search" parameterOrder="xml">
            <wsdl:input message="impl:searchRequest" name="searchRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="impl:searchResponse" name="searchResponse"/>
            <wsdl:fault message="impl:CFCInvocationException" name="CFCInvocationException"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="IDSearch.cfcSoapBinding" type="impl:IDSearch">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="search">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="searchRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://corpwsdl.oneninetwo" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="searchResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://corpwsdl.oneninetwo" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="CFCInvocationException">
                <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="CFCInvocationException" namespace="http://corpwsdl.oneninetwo" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="IDSearch">
        <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
            Main ID Search Web Service  </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:port binding="impl:IDSearch.cfcSoapBinding" name="IDSearch.cfc">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8001/exp?wsdl"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

index with client:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8001/exp';

var options = {
    disableCache: true,
    escapeXML: true,
    envelopeKey: 'SOAP-ENV'
};

var args = {
    xml: '<![CDATA['+xml+']]>'
    //xml : '<test>hello</test>'
};

soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, client) {
    client.search(args, function (err, result, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            console.log("Last request: \n", client.lastRequest + "\n");
        }

        var parsingOptions = {
            'object': true,
            'sanitize': false
        };
        console.log("Response \n\n", body);

        //var jsonResult = parser.toJson(body, parsingOptions);
        //console.log(jsonResult['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['ns1:searchResponse']['searchReturn']['$t']);
    });
});
```

server.js

```
var soap = require('soap');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var bp = require('body-parser');
var xmlParser = require('xml');
var app = express();

////app.use(bp.json());

console.log("Starting 192com SOAP service");

var myService = {
    IDSearch : { // wsdl:service
        IDSearch : { // wsdl:port
            search: function (args) {
                return {
                    status: "good"
                };

            }
        }
    }
}


var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('test/192com/192com.wsdl', 'utf8');

//body parser middleware are supported (optional)
app.use(bp.raw({type: function(){return true;}, limit: '20mb'}));
app.listen(8001, function(){
    //Note: /wsdl route will be handled by soap module
    //and all other routes & middleware will continue to work
    soap.listen(app, '/wsdl', myService, xml);
});

app.get('/exp', function (req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    res.send(xml);
});
```

When i go to localhost:8001/exp i get WSDL

when I execute soap client i get this response:

```
error:  { Fault: 
   { faultcode: 500,
     faultstring: 'Invalid XML',
     detail: 'Error: Unexpected close tag\nLine: 5\nColumn: 7\nChar: >',
     statusCode: 500 },
  response:
```

Response

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /exp</pre>
</body>
```

So anyone have ideas what's wrong with my server.js or wsdl ?

Answer (score 2):

Your soap server needs to listen to '/exp' route, not '/wsdl' route, and your express app sholdn't handle '/exp' route with app.get().

Then the soap server will handle the route '/exp?wsdl' automatically to provide wsdl info as a response to the client's get request. 
After that your client will post a request and it will be handled according to the config inside the xml file and the services provided to the soap.listen function.